# How to enable virsh console on Centos Atomic host?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virsh

I've Installed Centos AtomicHost Os on KVM , I just want to enable virsh console on it ! 
Tried below method but its is not working.
1. Added console=tty0 on /etc/grub/defailt

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rhgb quiet console=ttyS0"
```

2. Added below lines on virsh edit As per this: https://linuxadmin.io/enable-virsh-console-kvm/

Comment: Could you describe what is not working?

Comment: I'm unable to login via virsh console , its hang & not showing any login.

Comment: That is the normal behavior for that image. Why do you need console access?

Comment: There is no getty running in that image, so no loggin prompt.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS Atomic images have the serial console redirected to kvm/qemu serial port.

To connect to the serial port and see the boot messages:

```
virsh list --all   # To list all VMs
virsh shutdown <centos-atomic-VM-name>  # Stop the VM
virsh start --console <centos-atomic-VM-name>   # Connect on the VM's console and start it
```

Comment: Thanks for your time - but i need to have this serial connection permanent , suppose in some situation if i cant reach the server using ssh then i can use virsh console <vm_name>  to access its console

Comment: You can use `virsh console <VM-name>` to connect to console when VM is running